# How to use toLowerCase() in a filter with javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have following code where i'm playing with:

```
function filterJSON(data, key1, value1, key2, value2){
  let result = data;
  if(key1 !=null && value1 != null && key1 !== "" && value1 !== ""){
    result = data.filter(d => d[key1] === value1)[0].children;
  }
  if(key2 !=null && value2 != null && key2 !== "" && value2 !== "") {
    result = result.filter(d2 => d2[key2] === value2)[0].children;
  }
  return result;
```

value1 and value2 are always lower case. I want to try something like this `d[key1].toLowerCase() === value1`, but this doesn't seems to work. I want to do the same for `d[key2]`. How could i handle this?
Basically I want the value of `d[key1]` to be lower cased

Thanks!

Comment: `d[key1].toLowerCase() === value1, but this doesn't seems to work.` can you elaborate this. while comparison is it giving you any error. is `d[key1]` is null sometime? any error you faced while doing `d[key1].toLowerCase() === value1`

Comment: As a side note, you don't need to check for
if(key1 !== null && value! !== null & key1 !== "" && value1 !== "")

You can simply check for
if(key1 && value)

Comment: @OnurÖnder `keys` can be will be `0`. so you cannot.

Comment: please add some data and some calls of the function and the wanted results.

Comment: @AZ_ yep, that would be a problem. It only works if you already know the type of keys is string.

Answer (score 2):

You can add check

```
data.filter(d => (d[key1] || '').toLowerCase() === value1)[0].children;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use [array.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) instead of [array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), if you want only one matching value from the array.

**YOU CAN USE**

```
result = (data.find(d => d[key1] && value1 
  && (d[key1].toLowerCase() === value1.toLowerCase())) || {}).children;
```

**INSTEAD of**

```
result = data.filter(d => d[key1] === value1)[0].children;
```

Comment: was just going to add this.

Comment: `"" will always match the first case if key and value are not there.`

function filterJSON(data, key1, value1, key2, value2) {
 let result = data.find(d => (key1 && value1 && key1.length && value1.length && d[key1].toLowerCase() === value1) ||
  (key2 && value2 && key2.length && value2.length && d[key2].toLowerCase() === value2)).children;
 return result;
}

Comment: @AZ, You are right. Thanks for pointing out the mistake I have done.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
result = data.filter(d => String(d[key1]).toLowerCase() === value1)[0].children;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, you want to filter existent keys with some value, you could check if the value of a property is truthy and then check against the wanted value.

If necessary, you could convert the property value to a string.

```
function filterData(data, key1, value1, key2, value2) {
    var filters = [[key1, value1], [key2, value2]].filter(a => a.every(Boolean));
    return data.filter(o => filters.every(([k, v]) => o[k].toLowerCase() === v));
}
```